# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0600cc for fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have implemented the `ViewPager` in  Fragment in my application which contains the Custom layout. Now in Custom layout of ViewPager there is a `TextView` and onClick of the `TextView` i would like to replace the current fragment with other fragment. Lets say with Fragment2.

I already tried to replace but its giving error for the Resource id of the `FrameLayout` where i want to load the fragment. I already checked the relevant solutions in SO but none helped me.

Please any one can guide me for this error. It would be really grateful and appreciable.

**Logcat:**

```
11-13 11:17:54.480: E/AndroidRuntime(3982): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-13 11:17:54.480: E/AndroidRuntime(3982): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0600cc for fragment OtherProfileFragment{40ceba28 #4 id=0x7f0600cc}
11-13 11:17:54.480: E/AndroidRuntime(3982):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:865)
11-13 11:17:54.480: E/AndroidRuntime(3982):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1083)
11-13 11:17:54.480: E/AndroidRuntime(3982):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
11-13 11:17:54.480: E/AndroidRuntime(3982):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1431)
11-13 11:17:54.480: E/AndroidRuntime(3982):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:420)
11-13 11:17:54.480: E/AndroidRuntime(3982):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
11-13 11:17:54.480: E/AndroidRuntime(3982):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-13 11:17:54.480: E/AndroidRuntime(3982):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-13 11:17:54.480: E/AndroidRuntime(3982):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
11-13 11:17:54.480: E/AndroidRuntime(3982):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-13 11:17:54.480: E/AndroidRuntime(3982):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-13 11:17:54.480: E/AndroidRuntime(3982):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
11-13 11:17:54.480: E/AndroidRuntime(3982):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
11-13 11:17:54.480: E/AndroidRuntime(3982):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is my code where onclick of `TextView` i am trying to load the Fragment.

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_feed_detail, container,
            false);
    m_tvProfileName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.afd_tvProfileName);
    m_tvProfileName.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            FragmentManager m_mange = m_context.getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fm = m_mange.beginTransaction();
            Fragment llf = new OtherFragment();
            Bundle m_bundle = new Bundle();
            m_bundle.putInt("Id", Id);
            llf.setArguments(m_bundle);
            fm.addToBackStack("Other");
            fm.replace(R.id.fragmentswitcherframe, llf); //This line throwing error
            fm.commit();
            getActivity().finish();

        }
    });

    return v;
}
```

Comment: Please post your layout xml for `activity_feed_detail`.

Comment: does R.id.fragmentswitcherframe belongs to the Activity that hosts the fragment?

Comment: @blackbelt Yes that belongs to the Activity which contains the `FrameLayout` and its an id of `FrameLayout.`

Comment: @Terry There is no issue with the layout. The problem is with the `fm.replace(R.id.fragmentswitcherframe, llf);` line only.

Comment: Than I guess it's an issue with the layout of `OtherProfileFragment`. Can you post the code and the layout of the Fragment?

Comment: There is no issue with the layout also. AFAIK there is problem with my `Fragment` only from where i am calling the Fragment from `onCreatView()`

Comment: have you tried to start the fragment with getchildfragmentmanager instead of m_context.getSupportFragmentManager();. Imo your way is wrong

Comment: The Java code that you posted is from your ViewPager Fragment?

Comment: Yes that is from viewPager Fragment.

Comment: The crash was because i was directly loading the Fragment though the another Fragment activity which is DetailsView was already open in background and without finishing it i was going to load the layout in Fragment which is in another activity. Now i have resolved the issue by finishing the previous fragment activity and load the layout after finishing and manage it using flag in onResume method of already loaded fragment.

Comment: @GrIsHu please post the corrected code i'm in same trouble

Comment: @GrIsHu can you please post your code, facing same issue.